# Problems in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django, server

I don't know why this problem happened.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvuMD.png)
These errors occur when you read a book and follow it. I don't know what to do. Give me a hand.

### Source Code

This is my fistsite.py source code.

fistsite.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
enter code here
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]
```

After changing the source code above
now fistsite.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('/polls', views.polls, name='polls'),
    path('/admin', views.admin, name='admin')
]
```

But there was an error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQaNn.png)

my projcet[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhS8H.png)

Comment: The URL you have entered does not exist on the server. You even see which are available.

Comment: Show your "fistsite.urls"

Comment: Just add path for domain url like this: path('', views.index, name='index')

Comment: can i see your url which you are giving

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have Django version > 2.0, you should add to your urls.py file something like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('/polls', views.polls, name='polls'),
    path('/admin', views.admin, name='admin')
]
```

Comment: An error occurs after trying.         ImportError: cannot import name 'views'

Comment: you should create the url.py inside your new-app. Not sure how you named it.

Answer (score 0):

So as shown in the error page, your Django project tried to go to localhost:8000/admin/ and localhost:8000/polls/ but the site you are trying to access in localhost:8000/ . You haven't defined any url pattern for capturing this scenario. What you can do is in your urls.py, add this line under urlpatterns :

```
urlpatterns=[
 path('', views.index, name='index'),
 ...............
]
```

This works if you are using Django version>2.0
If you are using Django version<2.0 then you can add this:

```
urlpatterns=[
 url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
 ...............
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access you "polls". After change your fistsite.pytry this
`url = "localhost:8000/polls/`
 and you are giving only `localhost:8000` if did not create any app then this url will work.